# Access Microsoft graph resources with an auth0 login

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, auth0

I'm having difficulties finding documentation for auth0 and microsoft graph integration. My end goal is to have a SPA that can login with a microsoft profile to auth0 (connected to azure ad). Then I want my app to get a token for microsoft graph and do some api calls.

As I've understood it so far, [auth0 does not allow you to get the access token to different identity providers in a front end application](https://auth0.com/docs/connections/calling-an-external-idp-api), but rather that they should use a proxy to get this token. My flow therefore is:

- I login with a SPA auth0 app (using a microsoft identity)
- This is then used to authenticate to a backend server using a api registration in auth0
- The backend has its seperate machine-to-machine app in auth0
- Backend api uses this seperate app to get access token to auth0 management api
- Current user is fetched (based on the logged in user from front end app login) from management api,
- Here i find an access token under the azure identity (if I do the same in the front end, the access tokens are omitted)
- Token does not work to call graph, I am unsure of where to send it next.

I am aware that the above is probably completely wrong, that's why I am here :)

My questions are:

1) Is it even possible to get an access token for microsoft graph starting from a login to auth0 in the way I want it to. If not, can it be done from a backend?
2) Does anyone have a link that discusses this, ideally with some code samples.

Comment: This sounds like you are on the right track. Are you getting errors when you are sending the azure identity token you get from the management api?

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first question:

> 1) Is it even possible to get an access token for microsoft graph starting from a login to auth0 in the way I want it to. If not, can it be done from a backend?

I have had the chance to authenticate apps using the microsoft identity library called MSAl whose documentation is found [here](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js). It gives a pretty detailed way to authenticate directly from your SPA.

I have also used the [microsoft javascript sdk](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-javascript) as it comes inbuilt with token caching and refreshing so that I do not need to build that for myself.

In relation to this,

> Does anyone have a link that discusses this, ideally with some code samples.

You can find the samples well described in the [samples](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-javascript/tree/dev/samples/browser) section of the SDK

I hope this helps.